# How to access bin/Debug (ConsoleApp) from WebApp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

Currently, I'm building a web application. Inside my solution, I have two project, the **WebApp** itself and a **ConsoleApp**. I pass a string from a View (WebApp) to the ConsoleApp to be processed. In the ConsoleApp, it requires to access the bin/Debug folder. I place folder `stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09` inside the bin/Debug and write it in a code:

```
...
var jarRoot = @"stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09\models";
...
```

I got an error

```
 Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09\models'.
```

What's wrong with it? How am I supposed to do to access inside the bin/Debug directory from WebApp?

Comment: And the folder is right? Has the folder right permissions?

Comment: @Emanuele yes I place it correctly. I think there's no permission. I don't really know about the permission or somekind like that

Answer (score 1):

The web page is not running from that exact location as in Windows forms... It uses the IIS location instead , you need to use server.mappath("folder2find") method in order to find ur folder

Check this for more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Could you give the sample code? Because the article you suggest is in VB Scripts. Thanks

Comment: string strPath = Server.MapPath(@"stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09\models");
      strPath will hold ur final path. :)